# connecting to https url using python

Tags: python, https

I am trying to connect to a https url using python.
URL has a list of files and purpose is to get the filename of the latest file.
I'm using below code to connect to url

```
connection=httplib.HTTPSConnection(urlname)
connection.request("GET","/")
response=connection.getresponse()
print(response.status)
```

But i am getting an error

```
File "C:\python\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
```

gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

I believe issue is coming from this line
connection.request("GET","/")
Kindly help to understand this line and error in particular.